# installing mysql on ubuntu 18.04, what is root password

Tags: ubuntu, password, mysql

I installed MySQL on ubunto 18.04 and it is asking me to root password, but I don't have it.

Mysql version is:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

what I did is as follow:

1. I followed instructions on this site to install MYSql : https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu/
2. When I try to run the shell, I am getting error 1698

   ```
   m@m-XPS-M1530:~/Documents$ /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p
   Enter password: 
   ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
   ```
3. I tried blank password and also root password of the Ubuntu root without any success.
4. I followed the instruction on this site to rest the password without any success: https://coderwall.com/p/j9btlg/reset-the-mysql-5-7-root-password-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts
5. I uninstall and reinstalled it to make sure that I followed steps correctly, without any success. https://linuxscriptshub.com/uninstall-completely-remove-mysql-ubuntu-16-04/

Any idea how I can fix this problem? 
I can uninstall and reinstall with a different instruction if required.

Comment: What happens if you run the client without using the `-p` option, `mysql -u root`?

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan same error.

Comment: Have you tied to type empty password? I had the same problem a few days ago. And it helped me. https://youtu.be/8RhO4qtIvOI